# No select account page in Azure's Google identity provider

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Service to login using Google account.

I would like to force the google account chooser to appear even if the user is logged in just with one account.

I know by using prompt=select_account in the url, I will be able to accomplish that. But Azure doesn't allow me to change the url by calling client.login('google').

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use client.logout() from you JavaScript prior to calling the mobile service?

Additionally any credential cache being used might need to be cleared to retrigger a redirect to the login dialog (including the account chooser)
Like:
sessionStorage.loggedInUser = null;

I assume here you are not using the PasswordVault credential cache?
var vault = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault();

My reference:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/#caching